# SQR string variable

Tags: report, sqr

I have a string variable which is getting approx 1184 var from query but it is displaying only 263 character in SQR report which is in CSV format. Please tell how to get whole character in my variable. Please help i m new to SQR Report

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough info in the question to answer. My best guess is that when the SQR is writing the output to the CSV formatted file, the results are being truncated by the file properties.

In SQR, files are opened with parameters:

```
!-- File is opened but will write only 300 characters
Open $myFile as 10 For-Writing Record=300
!-- other code
Write 10 From $var1 $comma $var2
!-- other code
```

If the file is opened for 300 characters, then if the total length of $var1 and $var2 are over 300, you'll have truncated results in the output.

This is my best guess since the truncation didn't happen on a binary number boundary like 255/256 or 511/512.

Answer (score 0):

We could potentially increase String variable size by modifying the SQR initialization file **(aka “sqlsize”)** to adjust the maximum allowed size of text string variables up to 64K-1 bytes if necessary.

The limiting factor in this particular case is not the size of the variable, but the maximum allowed length of a single LET command – **the default for that is only 2048 bytes**. I believe your environment is set to use the default.

Try increasing the size using the above comment